# Finding span that is equal to intersection of 2 subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

$U = ⟨(1,1,3),(-5,-3,-15)⟩$ and $W = ⟨(4,4,9),(-44,-34,-120)⟩$
I need to find some vector $X$ such that:

$U∩W=\text{span}\{X\}$ , $X=[x, y, z]$

I tried to solve $a(1,1,3)+b(-5,3,-15)=c(4,4,9)+d(-44,-34,-120)$

which gives the general solution (it is correct according to linear equation calculators):

$d(-3,5,4,1)$

So a vector in $U∩W$ will be $d(-3, 5, 4)$

Which means $\text{span}(-3, 5, 4)$, but it's not the answer

Comment: Will you please share with us what is the answer?

Comment: I don't know it. It is taken from web homework and I can see the answer only if I have 0 attempts left

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, $(-3,5,4)$ neither belongs to $U$ nor to $W$.

The solutions of $a(1,1,3)+b(-5,3,-15)=c(4,4,9)+d(-44,-34,-120)$ are the quadruplets $(a,b,c,d)$ of the form $(-3\lambda,5\lambda,4\lambda,\lambda)$, for some $\lambda\in\Bbb R$. Putting $\lambda=-\frac12$, you will get the vector $(14,9,42)$, since\begin{align}(14,9,42)&=\frac32(1,1,3)-\frac52(-5,3,-15)\\&=-2(4,4,9)-\frac12(-44,-34,-120).\end{align}So, $U\cap W=\operatorname{span}\bigl\{(14,9,42)\bigr\}$.

Comment: Can u explain what  (87λ,−5λ,−16λ,−4λ) mean?

Comment: It means $(87\times\lambda,-5\times\lambda,-16\times\lambda,-4\times\lambda)$; $\lambda$ is an arbitrary real number.

Comment: I mean where did that come from. I found (a,b,c,d)=(-3,5,4,1), what's the next step?

Comment: If $(a,b,c,d)=(-3,5,4,1)$, then$$a(1,1,3)+b(-5,3,-15)=(-30,10,-90)$$and$$c(4,4,9)+d(-44,-34,-120)=(-28, -18, -84).$$Therefore, I don't understand how is it that you claim that $(a,b,c,d)=(-3,5,4,1)$ is a solution. It is not.

Comment: I'm sorry, $(-5,3,-15)$ was supposed to be $(-5,-3,-15)$... Then the vector of the intersection is $(-28,-18,-84)$ and is X in the question. 
Still thanks for help, I didn't actually know I need to multiply the solution vector back.

Comment: If that's so, then why did you not edit the question?

Answer (score 0):

First, we find simpler basis for these subspaces:

$\left[\begin{matrix}1&1&3\\-5&-3&-15\end{matrix}\right]\sim\left[\begin{matrix}1&1&3\\0&2&0\end{matrix}\right]\sim\left[\begin{matrix}1&1&3\\0&1&0\end{matrix}\right]\sim\left[\begin{matrix}1&0&3\\0&1&0\end{matrix}\right].$

and

$\left[\begin{matrix}4&4&9\\-44&-34&-120\end{matrix}\right]\sim\left[\begin{matrix}4&4&9\\0&10&-21\end{matrix}\right]\sim\left[\begin{matrix}1&1&9/4\\0&1&-21/10\end{matrix}\right]\sim\left[\begin{matrix}1&0&87/20\\0&1&-21/10\end{matrix}\right].$

Then, to produce a common vector, for some , $a,b\in\Bbb{R}$ $$\vec v_c=a(1,0,3)+b(0,1,0)=a(1,0,87/20)+b(0,1,-21/10)$$ which gives $3a=\frac{87}{20}a-\frac{21}{10}b$ or $9a=14b$. Choosing $a=14$ and $b=9$, a common vector is $\vec v_c=(14,9,42)$. Hence,
$$U\cap W=\{(14k,9k,42k)|k\in\Bbb{R}\}.$$